# Replacing elements in a list if substring matches

Tags: python

I have a `colnames` list

`colnames = ['Time', 'Centre position X', 'Centre position Y', 'In platform', 'In nw quad', 'In ne quad', 'In sw quad', 'In se quad', 'In perimeter']`

I would like to replace some elements in `colnames` with its substring alternative. The list of substrings alternatives are

`altnames = ['Time', 'X', 'Y', 'NE', 'NW', 'SW', 'SE', 'Platform']`

An original column name can be replaced by an alternative if the alternative is a substring of the original (case insensitive). So, I should end up with `['Time', 'X', 'Y', 'Platform', 'NW', 'NE', 'SW', 'SE', 'In perimeter']`.

I am able to currently solve this using a list comprehension and a function that uses a for loop.

```
def try_replacing(colname):
    for altname in altnames:
        if altname.lower() in colname.lower():
            return altname
    return colname

new_colnames = [try_replacing(colname) for colname in colnames]
```

However, I am wondering if there is a faster way that doesn't involve a for loop?

Comment: You could use a 1:1 dictionary mapping between `colnames` and your desired column names, but I also don't see a reason why you can't just... use `altnames` to begin with?

Comment: @blorgon `altnames` isn't in the same order and doesn't have things like `In perimeter`

Comment: OP, what you're asking for requires at least one `for` loop, however you can reduce this solution down to one `for` loop using either technique shown by Barmar's and my answers.

Comment: If the names are predefined, you can simply use a dict. If they're not predefined, then you can improve your code by removing an altname once matched, so the next iteration of for loop has fewer candidates to look through.

Comment: Use “.zip()” and iterate with one for-loop

Comment: @ZainArshad Zip creates tuples in order, which wouldn't work. OP said _altnames isn't in the same order_. There's really no need to over engineer this trivial problem.

Comment: Seems like OP needs to clarify if this information all known *a priori*, as Barmar's answer and mine are interpreting OP's problem differently.

Comment: Another thing: does it have to match whole words? `X` and `Y` could be in the middle of words

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of the outer `for` loop, since you have to go through all the items in `colnames`.

You can replace the inner loop with a regular expression that matches any of the strings in `altnames`. If it matches, you return the part of the string that matches. And you can use `re.IGNORECASE` to do this case-insensitively.

```
import re

altnames = ['Time', 'X', 'Y', 'NE', 'NW', 'SW', 'SE', 'Platform']
altnames_re = re.compile('|'.join(altnames), re.IGNORECASE)
new_colnames = []
for colname in colnames:
    m = altnames_re.search(colname)
    if m:
        new_colnames.append(m.group(0))
    else:
        new_colnames.append(colname)
```

Comment: @Blorgon The fact he's doing case-insensitive matching suggests that it's not fixed strings. I've edited my answer....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't actually need to search unknown strings for a substring, you can use a dictionary of alternate names and the `dict.get()` method:

```py
altnames = {'Centre position X': 'X', 'Centre position Y': 'Y', 'In nw quad': 'NW', 'In ne quad': 'NE', 'In sw quad': 'SW', 'In se quad': 'SE', 'In platform': 'Platform'}
colnames = [altnames.get(name, name) for name in colnames]
```

This uses `dict.get(key, default)` to return the alternate name if one is defined in the dictionary, or the name itself if one isn't defined: e.g.: `Time` is not present in `altnames`, so return `Time` itself.

Comment: I assume he's looking for substrings because the strings in `colnames` aren't known ahead of time.

Comment: But I mean `nw` should match `In nw quad`, `go nw`, etc.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting OP's problem. They state that they have a predefined list of column names, and the alternative names they'd like to use. OP seems to be misusing the word "substring" here, since they already have a pre-defined list of alternative names ready to replace another pre-defined list of names.

Comment: I don't see where OP states that `colnames` isn't known ahead of time...?

Comment: The use of the word "substring" is a misnomer because no searching needs to be performed, at least according to the information OP has provided.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your original column names have fewer parts than the alternate names, it would be more efficient to perform the lookup in the other direction.  You can achieve that by turning your altnames into a dictionary:

```
colnames = ['Time', 'Centre position X', 'Centre position Y', 
            'In platform', 'In nw quad', 'In ne quad', 
            'In sw quad', 'In se quad', 'In perimeter']
altnames = ['Time', 'X', 'Y', 'NE', 'NW', 'SW', 'SE', 'Platform']

altDict      = {n.lower():n for n in altnames}

new_colnames = [ next((altDict[n] for n in c.lower().split() if n in altDict),c)
                for c in colnames ]

print(new_colnames)
['Time', 'X', 'Y', 'Platform', 'NW', 'NE', 'SW', 'SE', 'In perimeter']
```